# Can I run a python 3 script on python 2 environment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Ok, so I'm creating a script on python 3 to do some silent installations.
My problem is that I do not know if the server is going to have python 3 available. Its possible that it has by default python 2 or some Unix Engineer installs python 3.
Now, my question is. Is it possible to run a python 3 script on a python 2?
Should I export the modules I need?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kindof. There is the [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) module. Its goal is

> Six is a Python 2 and 3 compatibility library. It provides utility
>   functions for smoothing over the differences between the Python
>   versions with the goal of writing Python code that is compatible on
>   both Python versions.

It won't do you any good if you need python 3 functionality. Its easy to install python 3 next to python 2 on most systems, so there really isn't much reason to try to struggle with it, though.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [python-future](http://python-future.org/overview.html) package for writing code that is compatible with Python 2.7 and Python 3.3+. It is somewhat more convenient than six and allows you to simply write idiomatic Python 3 almost everywhere.